# Querying "pairs" in large table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**UPDATED**

I have a large table in SQL Server 2014 where I need to find "pairs" corresponding to required proximity between each value in a keyfield. In real life it's a search of *all* locations by given proximity, without center of searching area. The keyfield has datatype Geography and filled with Points of coordinates on the map.

```
create table data
(
   id        int, 
   keyfield  geography
);

id    keyfield
-------------- 
1          a,b 
2          g,h
3          c,d
4          k,l
5          x,z
```

When searching for pairs of locations with a distance less than N the  expected result would be

```
id1   id2
------------- 
1     3      <- distance between 1 and 3 is less than N
2     4      <- distance between 2 and 4 is less than N
```

So far (thanks for comments on "duplicates") I have

```
select t1.id, t2.id,  
from data t1, data t2  
where t1.keyfield.STDistance(t2.keyfield) < N
and t1.id < t2.id
```

or

```
create table search
(
   id1 int,
   id2 int 
);
--------------

declare @id int  
declare @g geography

declare c cursor for  
select id, keyfield from data

open c   
fetch next from c into @id, @g   

while @@fetch_status = 0   
begin   
       insert into search
       select @id, id from data
       where keyfield.STDistance(@g) < N
       and @id < id

       fetch next from c into @id, @g
end   

close c   
deallocate c
```

Both work unacceptable slow even on small sets with 10-20K of records.

Again, it's not a search of locations within N radius from central Point(y,z) but a search of all locations what have distance N between each other.

Comment: use `t1.id < t2.id` in `where`.

Comment: in real life `keyfield` is not a number but other value

Comment: @Alex define "_other value_" with examples please

Comment: sorry it should've been `id`.

Comment: what is table2?

Comment: sorry a typo was there - the table is only one (corrected)

Comment: if keyfield isnt a number how you calculate 50 difference?

Comment: The demo is solveable, however, the real use case is a black box.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza proximity will be calculated in a `myfunction` that use values of myfunction and returns a value (e.g. 50). in real life keyfield is not a number but other value. Let me check if where with `t1.id < t2.id` will help

Comment: Isee, then for clarity you can use special string to show that.

Comment: Alex, none of this answers will solve the performance issue. Can you share the function definition?

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz true, they helped to remove duplicates (thanks,  everyone!) but this was not my real issue. The real problem is that search is slow.

Comment: What is the distance you are going to use?

Comment: I need only short distances, e.g. my current try was for N=50 (50meters, SRID=4326, or 0.03 miles) within coordinates limited by 200x500 km (125x250 miles). My test set has 20K of records with objects that should tipically have distances longer than 50m to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "distance" function is symmetric, then:

```
select t1.id, t2.id
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id < t2.id and myfunction(t1.keyfield, t2.keyfield) < 50;
```

This is going to be expensive on a large table, so it probably will not solve your actual problem.

I would suggest that you ask another question, providing more information and examples about what the fields look like and what the logic of the "distance" function is.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t1.id, t2.id
 from table1 t1
 join table1 t2
   ON t2.id between t1.keyfield - 50 and t1.keyfield + 50
  AND t1.id < t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just specify the difference on the `JOIN` condition like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([id] int, [keyfield] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([id], [keyfield])
VALUES
    (1, 100),
    (2, 200),
    (3, 130),
    (4, 201),
    (5, 999);

SELECT t1.id ,
       t1.keyfield ,
       t2.id,
       t2.keyfield
FROM #Table1 t1
INNER JOIN #Table1 t2 ON t2.keyfield <= t1.keyfield + 50 AND t2.keyfield > t1.keyfield

DROP TABLE #Table1
```

**Ouptut:**

```
id  keyfield    id  keyfield
1   100         3   130
2   200         4   201
```

This doesn't take into account your function, as you've not specified what that does. Hence, I removed the `WHERE` clause, which might give you an alternate approach.